# What can I do to make the "gcloud beta interactive" feature work for the "gsutil" and "bq" commands in the Google Cloud SDK?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gcloud, gsutil

I installed "Google Cloud SDK". Afterwards I installed the "beta" component with the command "gcloud components install beta". Afterwards I activated the "gcloud beta interactive" feature with the command "gcloud beta interactive". For the commands "gcloud" and "kubectl" everything works properly; when I type "gcloud" or "kubectl" and then add a space, all the possible commands appear. However, when I type "gsutil" or "bq" and then add a space, nothing happens. If I press the key Tab multiple times, nothing happens either.

To attempt to solve this, I created two files, ".bashrc" and "bash_profile". This is what I wrote in them:

This is the ".bashrc" file:

```
    alias hello='echo Hello1'
    source DirectoryPath/completion.bash.inc
    source DirectoryPath/path.bash.inc
```

This is the "bash_profile" file:

```
    alias hello='echo Hello2'
    source DirectoryPath/completion.bash.inc
    source DirectoryPath/path.bash.inc
```

In my real ".bashrc" and ".bash_profile" files I used the real path of the "completion.bash.inc" and "path.bash.inc" files, instead of the word "DirectoryPath".

If I execute the command "source .bashrc" and then execute the command "hello", the word "Hello1" is returned. This proves the ".bash_profile" file is being used by the Google Cloud SDK.
If I execute the command "source .bash_profile" and then execute the command "hello", the word "Hello2" is returned. This proves the ".bash_profile" file is being used by the Google Cloud SDK.

My attempted solution failed. For me, the "gcloud beta interactive" feature does not work for the commands "gsutil" and "bq".
What can I do to make the "gcloud beta interactive" feature work for the "gsutil" and "bq" commands in the Google Cloud SDK?